# Extraer un millón de emails, desde un txt con PHP

Tags: php, txt

tengo un archivo `txt` con emails, hay casi un millón de emails algo como 978.000 (algunos son repetidos).

Pero mi `script` es ineficiente, no logra hacerlo de forma "rápida" y si los números de emails superan el millón prácticamente no puede extraerlos.

Lo que tengo hecho es lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen('emails.txt', 'r');
    $salida = fopen("salida.txt", "w+");
    if (!$fp) {
        echo 'ERROR: No ha sido posible abrir el archivo. Revisa su nombre y sus permisos.';
        exit;
    }    
    $loop = 0; 
    while (!feof($fp)) { 
        while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
            if (preg_match("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $line, $result)) {
                preg_match("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $line, $result);
                $result = join("\n", $result);
                $emails_unicos[] = $result;
                $emails_unicos = array_unique($emails_unicos);
            }
        }
        foreach ($emails_unicos as $email_unico) {
            echo rtrim($email_unico, "com") . '<br/>';;
            fwrite($salida, $email_unico);
            $loop++;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Lo que hago en mi `script` es leer los datos del `txt`, filtrarlos y eliminar lo duplicados.

Pero ¿se podría mejorar de alguna forma? para optimizarlo y que pueda extraer más de un millón de usuarios.

Comment: ¿Puedes definir lo que es para tí rápido? ¿Cuánto tiempo está tardando ahora y en cuanto tiempo esperas que se puedan procesar?

Comment: 300 mil lineas en 1 minuto las lee, pero 1 millon tarda eternidades.

Comment: ¿Cuanto es una eternidad....? 10 minutos, 10horas, 10 días...?

Comment: tarda mas de 2 horas

Comment: No soy experto en php pero si se que lo que quiere hacer debe hacerlo con programacion asíncrona o en varios hilos. No se porque esta metiendo tantos datos en un solo archivo. No sería mejor crear archivos con 300 mil líneas cada uno y en varios hilos cargar todos esos archivos en lugar de tratarlo de hacer bruscamente en uno solo ?????

Comment: Para optimizar te recomiendo indexar tus emails (con la primera letra o las dos primeras letras del email) y la busqueda entre los ya recorridos sea mucho más rápida, que es similar a lo que recomienda @RichardVíquezPérez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1ra opción:**
Tengo esta opción que podría servirte:

```
$lines = file("emails.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$lines = array_intersect_key($lines, array_unique(array_map(function($v){
    // Aquí podrías poner tus expresiones regulares
    return trim($v);
}, $lines)));
$salida = fopen("salida.txt", "w+");
foreach ($lines As $line)
    fwrite($salida, "$line\n");
fclose($salida);
```

**2da opción:**
Y bueno se me ocurre ésta otra forma modificando tu código para que no tengas que iterar dos veces:

```
set_time_limit(3600); // Aqui va el tiempo de ejecución según el tiempo que requieras
$fp = fopen('emails.txt', 'r');
$salida = fopen("salida.txt", "w+");
if (!$fp) {
    echo 'ERROR: No ha sido posible abrir el archivo. Revisa su nombre y sus permisos.';
    exit;
}

$loop = 0;
$arrEmails = array();
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line = fgets($fp);
    if (preg_match("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $line, $result)) {
        preg_match("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $line, $result);
        $result = join("\n", $result);
        if (!in_array($result, $arrEmails)) { // Aquí pregunto si el email no existe en el array (y se escribe en el archivo si no existe)
            $arrEmails[] = $result;
            fwrite($salida, $result);
            $loop++;
        }
    }
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Muy buena acotación, por otra parte tomé tu código para optimizarlo un poco más. Saludos

Comment: Genial, funciono perfectamente, gracias

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @Cristian ? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0):

Basandome en el codigo de @Israel-ICM te sugiero indexarlo con las dos primeras siglas de cada correo en un arreglo multidimensional, ya que estas manejando una cantidad muy alta de datos (1 millón).

PD: No estoy seguro si funciona porque no he ejecutado, pero desde mi interprete mental funciona, pruebalo y me comentas.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0); // Se define en 0 para que no tenga limite de tiempo de ejecución.
$fp = fopen('emails.txt', 'r');
$salida = fopen("salida.txt", "w+");
if (!$fp) {
    echo 'ERROR: No ha sido posible abrir el archivo. Revisa su nombre y sus permisos.';
    exit;
}

$loop = 0;
$arrIndex = array();

while (!feof($fp)) {
    while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
        if (preg_match("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $line, $result)) {
            $result = join("\n", $result);
            if (!in_array($result, $arrIndex[substr($result, 0,2)])) { // Aquí pregunto si el email no existe en el array (y se escribe en el archivo si no existe)
                $arrIndex[substr($result, 0,2)][] = $result;
                fwrite($salida, $result);
                $loop++;
            }
        }
    }
}

fclose($fp);
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.